# Expand tree view dynamically in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have some values stored in my list. I am populating my tree view with this code:

```
foreach (DataRow row in ResultSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode();
    newNode.Text = row["Folder_Name"].ToString();
    newNode.Value = row["Folder_Code"].ToString() + "/1" + '@' + row["Short_Name"].ToString();
    newNode.PopulateOnDemand = true;
    // newNode.NavigateUrl = "DisplayNodebygreed.aspx?value=" + newNode.Value + "";  
    newNode.ImageUrl = "~/Images/folderSmall2.jpg";
    TreeView_Parent_Child.Nodes.Add(newNode);
}

abc = (List<string>)Session["submainlevel"];
```

In this list of mine, I have values stored such as

```
1st position 2
2nd : 3
3rd : 3
```

Now I need to check the value of the of tree that has been populated by the initial code and expand more according to values of the values that I have in the list as stated just above. How can I go about it. I am using a code which I got from an answer on stackoverflow. Below is my code that I am trying to execute to populate and make it expanded accordingly.

```
foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView_Parent_Child.Nodes)
    if (node.Value.Split('/')[0] == abc[a].Split('/')[0])
        ExpandMyLitleBoys(node, abc);

private void ExpandMyLitleBoys(TreeNode node, List<string> path)
{
    path.RemoveAt(0);
    node.Expand();
    if (path.Count == 0)
            return;

    foreach (TreeNode mynode in node.ChildNodes)
        if (mynode.Text == path[0].Split('/')[0])
            ExpandMyLitleBoys(mynode, path); //recursive call    
}
```

Please help. I am working on a live project. Please.

Comment: That's the most disturbing method name I've ever seen...

Comment: @Slump : I have not written that function .. I got it from stackoverflow. Please help.